# jQuery How to get the top-most container ID?

Tags: jquery

on my page, I have many html controls looking like that:

```
<span id="pic1" class="container">
    <span class="inner">
       <span class="img"></span>
       <span class="strip"></span>
       <span class="remove_the_main_container"></span>
    </span>
</span>
```

All I wanna do, is to remove (by using jQuery) the `span` with `class="container"` when user clicks at the `span` with `class="remove_the_main_container"`. The problem is - **How to get the ID  of the top-most container inside which is placed that clicked span (`class="remove_the_main_container"`) ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery's `.closest()` method](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the first ancestor that matches the selector you give it.

```
$('.remove_the_main_container').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.container').remove();
});
```

This way if there are other ancestors with the `container` class, they won't be affected.

Or if you meant that you wanted to remove that `span`, but not its content, then go to the `.inner` element, and use [jQuery's `unwrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

```
$('.remove_the_main_container').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.inner').unwrap();
});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that .closest() was introduced with 1.3.  If you are stuck with 1.2.x for some reason (like a stock Drupal install), then .parents('some_selector').eq(0) is equivalent.

Comment: Let's say I have 4 spans: [1] [2] [3] [4]. If I remove 2nd, I'd like to animate sliding to the left the 3rd & 4th span. How to do that ?

Comment: @Tony - Not sure exactly what you mean. I'd say give it a try using jQuery, and if you're stuck on something, post a new question. :o)

Answer (score 5):

You should not need the ID to remove it.

```
$('.remove_the_main_container').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.container').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the topmost container always has a class of `container`, you could do something like this to get the id:

```
var id = $(".remove_the_main_container").parents(".container").attr("id");
```

But you don't *need* the id to remove the container. You could do something like this:

```
$(".remove_the_main_container").bind("click", function(eventObj) {
    $(this).parents(".container").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is relative to which instance of `remove_the_main_container` so it requires no IDs or anything of that nature.

```
jQuery('.remove_the_main_container').bind('click', function (e) {
      jQuery(e.currentTarget).parents('.container').remove();
});
```